# Mounting a power supply

Tags: power-supply, mini-itx

I got a mini-itx case and a DC-to-DC power supply, which is 5cm wide (typical seems 3cm, but this one's 200W...).  It won't fit into the power supply mounting pins in the case, so I'm considering just using cable ties to tie it to a HDD bay.

It *is* a power supply, so I'm concerned about shorts.  (I guess I would still be concerned for the component if it was anything else, but doing this wrong might be personally dangerous.)  Would, say, a sponge between the PCB and HDD bracket be effective?  Is this a really bad idea?

The case is a [Viako Mini Self](http://viako.en.ec21.com/Viako_Mini_Letter_SELF_DIY--4327891_4327902.html).  It's got a HDD mounting bracket that kind of floats above the motherboard (it screws onto opposite walls of the case).  You can use acrylic pieces but mine are all aluminum.

The power supply is the fourth item on [this list](http://www.eleparts.co.kr/front/productblist.php?brandcode=1404): a Modcom ST-DCP 200W (sorry, can't seem to find an english version, or a static link to the item itself).

Comment: How about some more info: power supply make/model, chassis make/model, etc. Pictures perhaps?

Comment: Hmm... a non boxed power supply in a PC? Not something I want to see anytime soon :P Seriously though, put the board on a set of standoffs (the same type used on a motherboard) and you should be fine.

Comment: @BillyONeal Pins for mounting it (with standoffs or without) exist on the case, but only accommodate boards that are up to 3cm wide (after installing the motherboard).  Are you suggesting adding pins?  I don't think I have the tools to drill through ~4mm of aluminum...

Comment: @bdares: All a standoff is is a bit to hold the board away from the metal mounting plate so that shorts don't happen. Most standoffs shipped with cases are designed to screw in to the case in specific positions, but that's by no means the only kind of standoff. Since you want to use zip-ties, you could probably make something workable with a couple bits of dowel rod and some screws.

Comment: @bdares: To clarify, you could screw dowel bits to the bottom of the circuit board to hold it away from the case, then zip tie the whole thing to the case. Or something similar.

Comment: @BillyONeal That sounds like a much better idea than a sponge.  Could you answerify your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to get away with a makeshift set of standoffs constructed from dowel rods. For example, just screw small pieces of dowel rod to the PSU board to hold it away from the metal of the case. Then Zip-Tie as you would normally.